# What are the negative effects of meditation?

Tags: decision-making, meditation

I see lots of articles touting the benefits of meditation. But what are the bad things about it? Maybe if a person has to make quick decisions, meditation would not be a good thing? This could be similar to a paridigm of "Thinking Fast, Thinking Slow" by Kahneman.

Comment: Not a drawback unique to mediation, but opportunity cost tends to be neglected in such discussions. e.g. spending 2 hours mediating might reduce stress, but perhaps TV reduces stress faster.

Comment: There is a thread on ReserchGate discussing the negative side effects of meditation: http://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_meditation_have_negative_side_effects/1

Answer (score 5):

The adverse effects of meditation as reported in scientific studies are as follows:

- relaxation-induced anxiety and panic
- paradoxical increases in tension
- less motivation in life
- boredom
- pain
- impaired reality testing
- confusion and disorientation
- feeling 'spaced out'
- depression
- increased negativity
- being more judgmental
- feeling addicted to meditation
- uncomfortable kinaesthetic sensations
- mild dissociation
- feelings of guilt
- psychosis-like symptoms
- grandiosity
- elation
- destructive behavior
- suicidal feelings
- defenselessness
- fear
- anger
- apprehension
- despair
- increased false-memory susceptibility

Also, anecdotal evidence suggests that meditation can worsen symptoms of some psychiatric problems.

Sources:

Study from 1992:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1428622

> Adverse effects of meditation: a preliminary investigation of
>   long-term meditators, by Shapiro DH Jr.
>
> Department of Psychiatry and Human Behavior, California College of Medicine, University of California, Irvine.
>
> Abstract
>
> Adverse effects of meditation were assessed in twenty-seven long term
>   meditators (average 4.27 years) both retrospectively (time one) and
>   prospectively at one month (time two) and six months (time three)
>   following a meditation retreat. At both time one and time three
>   subjects reported significantly more positive effects than negative
>   from meditation. However, of the twenty-seven subjects, seventeen
>   (62.9%) reported at least one adverse effect, and two (7.4%) suffered
>   profound adverse effects. When subjects at time one were divided into
>   three groups based on length of practice (16.7 months; 47.1 months;
>   105 months) there were no significant differences in adverse effects.
>   How the data should be interpreted, and their implications both for
>   the clinical and psychotherapeutic use of meditation as a
>   relaxation/self-control strategy, and as a technique for facilitating
>   personal and spiritual growth, are discussed. Limitations of the study
>   and suggestions for future research are also offered.

Meta-analysis from 2000:

> Meditation: concepts, effects and uses in therapy by Alberto
>   Perez-De-Albeniz and Jeremy Holmes
>
> International Journal of Psychotherapy, Mar2000, Vol. 5 Issue 1,
>   p49, 10p
>
> Abstract: This article reviews 75 scientific selected articles in the
>   field of meditation, including Transcendental Meditation among others.
>   It summarizes definitions of meditation, psychological and physiological
>   changes, and negative side-effects encountered by 62.9% of meditators
>   studied. While the authors did not restrict their study to TM, the
>   side-effects reported were similar to those found in the "German
>   Study" of Transcendental Meditators: relaxation-induced anxiety and
>   panic; paradoxical increases in tension; less motivation in life;
>   boredom; pain; impaired reality testing; confusion and disorientation;
>   feeling 'spaced out'; depression; increased negativity; being more
>   judgmental; feeling addicted to meditation; uncomfortable kinaesthetic
>   sensations; mild dissociation; feelings of guilt; psychosis-like
>   symptoms; grandiosity; elation; destructive behavior; suicidal
>   feelings; defenselessness; fear; anger; apprehension; and despair.

New study shows increase in cortisol reactivity (a biological marker of stress): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24767614

> The present study provides an initial indication that brief
>   mindfulness meditation training buffers self-reported psychological
>   stress reactivity, but also increases cortisol reactivity to social
>   evaluative stress. This pattern may indicate that initially brief
>   mindfulness meditation training fosters greater active coping efforts,
>   resulting in reduced psychological stress appraisals and greater
>   cortisol reactivity during social evaluative stressors.

Another new study shows increased susceptibility to false memories:

http://pss.sagepub.com/content/26/10/1567

Increased False-Memory Susceptibility After Mindfulness Meditation by Brent M. Wilson, Laura Mickes, Stephanie Stolarz-Fantino, Matthew Evrard and Edmund Fantino in Psychololgical Science

> Abstract
>
> The effect of mindfulness meditation on false-memory susceptibility
>   was examined in three experiments. Because mindfulness meditation
>   encourages judgment-free thoughts and feelings, we predicted that
>   participants in the mindfulness condition would be especially likely
>   to form false memories. In two experiments, participants were randomly
>   assigned to either a mindfulness induction, in which they were
>   instructed to focus attention on their breathing, or a mind-wandering
>   induction, in which they were instructed to think about whatever came
>   to mind. The overall number of words from the Deese-Roediger-McDermott
>   paradigm that were correctly recalled did not differ between
>   conditions. However, participants in the mindfulness condition were
>   significantly more likely to report critical nonstudied items than
>   participants in the control condition. In a third experiment, which
>   tested recognition and used a reality-monitoring paradigm,
>   participants had reduced reality-monitoring accuracy after completing
>   the mindfulness induction. These results demonstrate a potential
>   unintended consequence of mindfulness meditation in which memories
>   become less reliable.

Official recommendations in the US:
http://nccam.nih.gov/health/meditation/overview.htm#sideeffects

> Side Effects and Risks
>
> Meditation is considered to be safe for healthy people. There have
>   been rare reports that meditation could cause or worsen symptoms in
>   people who have certain psychiatric problems, but this question has
>   not been fully researched. People with physical limitations may not be
>   able to participate in certain meditative practices involving physical
>   movement. Individuals with existing mental or physical health
>   conditions should speak with their health care providers prior to
>   starting a meditative practice and make their meditation instructor
>   aware of their condition.

Comment: In the press: http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2014/06/the-dark-knight-of-the-souls/372766/?single_page=true

Comment: Dr. Willoughby Britton, Contemplative Stuides Initiative, Brown University conducts research on this subject: https://vimeo.com/18819660

Comment: I have added two newer studies which show increased cortisol response and false memory susceptibility.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but maybe just add a bit more about the scope and validity errors of the studies you have cited, and your dot points are sweeping statements, more accuracy is required.

Comment: @tristo Thank you, for the constructive criticism. I'll try to improve the answer when I have time. Regarding the dot points, I have tried to preserve the original wording. The fact is that the question is very broad. There is close to 30 side effects listed. Quite a few brands of meditative practices have been reviewed by researchers. Something like "relaxation-induced anxiety" by itself would legitimately be the subject of SE question and answers and moreover of specific research.